# How to search for \list but not list?

Tags: support, search

I'm looking for questions on the main site that have `\list` in their body but need to avoid question that have `list`. Is there a search syntax I can use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Search terms would be [`body:"\list" -"list"`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=body%3A%22%5Clist%22+-%22list%22):

[image]